# IE8 don't show <figure> Tag although html5shiv

Tags: image, internet-explorer-8, typo3, figure, html5shiv

my IE8 doesn't show images inner the figure tag.

TYPO3 Installation 6.1.x
DOCTYPE HTML5
css styled content (latest)

Frontend: Text & Image will shown as

```
<div class="csc-textpic-imagewrap">
<div class="csc-textpic-center-outer">
<div class="csc-textpic-center-inner">
  <figure class="csc-textpic-image csc-textpic-last">
      <img height="308" width="828" alt="" src="fileadmin/media/image.JPG">
 </figure>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I 've included HTML5shiv Script - nothing happens ..  then I tries to unwrap the figure element with jQuery - nothing happens

Has anyone an idea how I can show my image wrapped with

Answer (score 1):

it was a responsive big

```
img {
  max-width: auto;
  width: 100%;
  /* and for IE 8 */
  width: auto\9;
}
```

That's it   Damn.!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

```
tt_content.image.20.rendering.singleNoCaption.singleStdWrap.wrap.override >
tt_content.image.20.rendering.noCaption.singleStdWrap.wrap.override >
```

Or instead of deleting it, replace it with whatever html you like.

Answer (score 0):

just set this in config typoscript

```
 doctype = html5
```